Can I post my article to an e-print archive (like arXiv) before submitting to an APS online journal?
I have read in some discussion forum that it should be safe, but I did not find any statement about this on the APS site.
If the answer is yes, does this rule apply for any e-print archive, other than arXiv?

https://www.aps.org/archives/publications/apsnews/201211/backpage.cfm found from first Google hit on ‘APS arxiv preprint’

From APS' Copyright FAQ (emphasis mine):

As the author of an APS-published article, may I post my article or a portion of my article on an e-print server?
The author has the right to post and update the article on a free-access e-print server using files prepared and formatted by the author. Any such posting made or updated after acceptance of the article for publication by APS should include a link to the online APS journal article abstract. In all cases, the appropriate bibliographic citation and notice of the APS copyright must be included.

On the Open Access and Publications Rights policy page, APS states

Green Open Access
For all subscription articles for which APS holds copyright, authors have the right to post and update the article on free-access e-print servers (repositories, including institutional and subject specific such as the arXiv) as long as the version of record prepared and/or formatted by APS or its vendors are not used for that purpose, and the APS copyright is clear. All article depositions should include a link/DOI to the published manuscript.

Your version prior to submission to the journal likely was not prepared or formatted by APS or its vendors, so you'd be in the clear as long as you'd be submitting to a free-access e-print archive. Repositories that charge a fee for providing access (do they exist?) may lead to APS imposing fees on submitting authors. If you're uncertain about whether a specific server qualifies, consider asking the journal directly. (A third scenario, which I've used personally, is posting to an internal, non-public institutional repository. The policy is unclear on such cases, but frankly APS tend to be quite author-friendly and presumably don't worry about what's not publicly available.)
APS' copyright agreement (applicable in most cases unless you publish under an open access license) includes text that effectively states the same as above. The Creative Commons Publication Agreement (for open access publications) does not include such an affirmative statement, but also barely restricts authors so I presume any "free-access e-print server" is still perfectly fine.

Actually APS allows to submit papers directly from ArXiv. This implies that you can post to ArXiv and then submit to an APS journal. The same rule should apply to e-print archives which adopt the same copyright policy as ArXiv. Your answer seems to confirm this...

@PFerro Posting to arXiv and then submitting to an APS journal is certainly allowed, no question about it. But arXiv is also special in that the site has been around since 1991 and has significant community adoption, so I think your asking whether there is a broadly applicable rule or an arXiv-specific one is sensible.

My question is also about arXiv, but mainly about other e-print archives. The problem is that arXiv has become a little stricter in accepting manuscripts. So I don't rule out the possibility that arXiv rejects my article, and that I have to post my preprint elsewhere.
